# Requesting assistance to resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class that has an inner non-static class which refers to the parent

```
public static class HighChartSeriesPercents {

    private final List<Entry> entries;
    private int total;
    @JsonIgnore
    private transient boolean percentsGenerated;
    @JsonIgnore
    private final int sortMode;

    public HighChartSeriesPercents() {
        this(0);
    }

    public HighChartSeriesPercents(int sortMode) {
        this.entries = new ArrayList<>();
        this.sortMode = sortMode;
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(entries);
    }

    public void add(String name, int value) {
        total += value;
        percentsGenerated = false;
        entries.add(new Entry(name, value));
    }

    @JsonProperty("size")
    public int size() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(entries);
    }

    private void calculatePercents() {
        for (Entry e : entries) {
            e.setPercent((double) e.getPercent() / (double) total);
        }
        percentsGenerated = true;
    }

    public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {

        private final String name;
        private final int value;
        private double percent;

        public Entry(String name, int value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public double getPercent() {
            if (!percentsGenerated) {
                calculatePercents();
            }
            return percent;
        }

        private void setPercent(double percent) {
            this.percent = percent;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entry o) {
            int r;
            if (sortMode == 0) {
                r = ObjectUtils.compare(name, o.name);
                if (r != 0) {
                    return r;
                }
                return ObjectUtils.compare(value, o.value);
            } else {
                r = ObjectUtils.compare(value, o.value);
                if (r != 0) {
                    return r;
                }
                return ObjectUtils.compare(name, o.name);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Whenever Jackson serialises this I get:

> Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through
>   reference chain:
>   my.package.HighChartSeriesPercents["entries"]); nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   my.package.HighChartSeriesPercents["entries"])

I tried making `Entry` final and adding a reference variable to the parent and accessing it, also annotating with `@JsonManagedReference` for the parents list of entries and `@JsonBackReference` for the child's reference to the parent.

Comment: Have you tried calling `calculatePercents()` on an instance of `HighChartSeriesPercents` with one or more `Entries`? You'll get an SO error, this is unrelated to Jackson

Comment: Agreed with previous comment; it looks like there's a pretty clear possibility of an SO with `Entry.getPercent()` <-> `calculatePercents()` -- @milkplusvellocet you should post that as an answer. If Jackson calls `Entry.getPercent()` to get the field value during serialization, it looks like your code could very easily lead to an SO.

Comment: Ah bloody hell, thanks guys, the `calculatePercents()` should be `e.value` not `e.getPercent()`. Thanks. milk, could you post an answer and I shall accept, feel free to post it as a code mistake and correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in above comment, the code posted can easily result in a `StackOverflowError`.

1. `Entry#getPercent()`
2. calls `HighChartSeriesPercents#calculatePercents`
3. calls `Entry#getPercent()` etc etc

so the problem is unrelated to Jackson.

If you change your logic to use `value` in `calculatePercents()` this will be averted.